# T-SQL check to see data is in range then select record from table A

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Table A

```
ID   name     date_from     date_to      region   manager
---------------------------------------------------------
1    Harry    2019-12-01    2020-01-01    south    ABC
1    Harry    2020-01-01    2020-03-01    north    BCD
1    Harry    2020-03-01       NULL       East     DCE
```

Table B

```
Date          name     H_time    T_time  
---------------------------------------
2019-12-01    Harry     30        20
2020-01-01    Harry     20        10
2020-02-01    Harry     40        50
2020-04-01    Harry     50        60
```

I wanted to check table B date falls into the date range above and return the specific region and manager info like...

Table C

```
Date          name     H_time    T_time   region  manager
---------------------------------------------------------
2019-12-01    Harry     30        20      south    ABC
2020-01-01    Harry     20        10      north    BCD
2020-02-01    Harry     40        50      north    BCD
2020-04-01    Harry     50        60      East     DCE
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: It would be better if you can show us the query that you have tried

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `join`:

```
select b.*, a.region, a.manager
from b join
     a
     on b.name = a.name and
        b.date >= a.date_from and
        (b.date <= date_to or a.date_to is null);
```

Comment: @DSP . . . Set up a db/SQL fiddle so I can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your expected result, this should do the trick

```
SELECT b.*, a.region, a.manager
FROM table_b b 
INNER JOIN table_a a on b.name = a.name 
WHERE
     (b.date >= a.date_from and b.date < a.date_to)
OR
     (b.date >= a.date_from and a.date_to IS NULL)
```